# Using the Range function with the Slot (#) function

Tags: graphics, dynamic, slot

I am writing a code to display longitudinal waves.
I started with the following, filling the slots using the Range function.

```
    l = {Blue, Disk[{3 Sin[(5) t + 0.1 #] + 1.4 #, 1}, 0.5]} & /@ 
   Range[25];
Animate[Evaluate[Graphics[l, PlotRange -> {{-4, 44}, All}]], {t, 0, 
  20. \[Pi]}, AnimationRate -> .3]
```

The slots control the x-position of the disks, as a result I get 25 disks beside each others. However, I want to obtain this single line of disks multiple times, each line under the other, as shown in the figure below. 
[image]
I tried to insert a new slot in the y-position of Disk function, but I do not know how to separate this new slot from the other two in the x-position, and assign it a new Range function. Can anyone help me in this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

nRow = 10;

nCol = 25;

l = {Blue, 
     Disk[{3 Sin[5 t + 0.1 #[[1]]] + 1.4 #[[1]], 1.5 #[[2]]}, 
      0.5]} & /@ Flatten[Array[{#1, #2} &, {nCol, nRow}], 1];

Animate[Evaluate[Graphics[l, PlotRange -> {{-4, 44}, All}]], {t, 0, 
  20. π}, AnimationRate -> .3]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bob! You are a Legend!

Answer (score 3):

#### [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html):

```
ClearAll[disks]
disks[t_, nc_, nr_] := Array[Disk[{3 Sin[5 t + 0.1 #] + 1.4 #, 1.5 #2}, 0.5] &, {nc, nr}];

Animate[Graphics[{Blue, disks[t, 25, 10]}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 44}, All}], {t, 0, 20.  π}, 
 AnimationRate -> .3]
```

[image]

#### [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html):

```
ClearAll[disks2]
disks2[t_, nc_, nr_] := Outer[Disk[{3 Sin[5 t + 0.1 #] + 1.4 #, 1.5 #2}, 0.5] &, 
 Range @ nc, Range @ nr];

Animate[Graphics[{Blue, disks2[t, 25, 10]}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 44}, All}], {t, 0, 20.  π}, 
 AnimationRate -> .3]
```

> same picture

#### [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html):

```
ClearAll[disks3]
disks3[t_, nc_, nr_] := Disk[{3 Sin[5 t + 0.1 #] + 1.4 #, 1.5 #2}, 0.5] & @@@ 
  Tuples[Range /@ {nc, nr}];

Animate[Graphics[{Blue, disks3[t, 25, 10]}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 44}, All}], {t, 0, 20. π}, 
 AnimationRate -> .3]
```

> same picture

```
ClearAll[disks4]
disks4[t_, nc_, nr_] := Disk[#, .5] & /@ 
  Tuples[{3 Sin[5 t + 0.1 Range[nc]] + 1.4 Range[nc], 1.5 Range[nr]}]

Animate[Graphics[{Blue, disks4[t, 25, 10]}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 44}, All}], {t, 0, 20. π}, 
 AnimationRate -> .3]
```

> same picture